# Centering a tooltip horizontally beneath parent without setting a static width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center a tooltip horizontally under its parent without setting a static width on the tooltip. Is this possible? Please refer to the code snippet below. I could adjust the absolute positioning to make it perfectly center, but since the length of the text will vary they will not all be centered.

```css
body {
margin: 20px;
}

.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 150%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Notifications</span>
</div>

<br/><br/><br/><br/>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Account</span>
</div>

<br/><br/><br/><br/>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Help</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easiest would be `translate()` instead a négative `margin`. It will work as long as the tooltip is not longer than the text itself ... it might go off screen

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}


/* see center */

.tooltip, .tooltiptext {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 50%, gray 50%);
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0)
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Notifications</span>
</div>

<br/><br/><br/><br/>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Account</span>
</div>

<br/><br/><br/><br/>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Help</span>
</div>
```